# Subclass overwrites value updated by Super class

Tags: java, oop

I have following piece of code in java. This prints null.
Why? Can someone please tell the init sequence of the below variable and this behavior

> Integer data = null;

```java
abstract class Super
{
    Super(int f)
    {
        init(f);
    }
    abstract void init(int f);
}

class Sub extends Super
{
    Integer data = null;
    
    Sub(int f)
    {
        super(f);
    }
    @Override
    void init(int f) {
        data = f;
    }

    public void showData()
    {
        System.out.println(this.data);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sub sub = new Sub(10);
        sub.showData();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use overridable methods in constructors. The problem is that `init` is invoked before `null` is assigned to `data`.

Comment: It's a quirk of initialization order. In general, just don't ever call instance methods while still in the constructor, and you'll be fine. Most IDEs will generate warnings if you do this, so it's easy to avoid.

Comment: the "*init sequence*" is detailed in the Java Language Specification [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) (mainly starting at this [paragraph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5-220))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (basic) initialization order of a constructor is:

- Invoke the super constructor
- Invoke the instance initializers (and field initializers, which are just syntactic sugar for field declaration + instance initializers)
- Execute the rest of the constructor

So, for:

```
class Sub extends Super
{
    Integer data = null;
    
    Sub(int f)
    {
        super(f);
    }

    // ...
}
```

this is the same as:

```
class Sub extends Super
{
    Integer data;
    
    Sub(int f)
    {
        super(f);
        data = null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, if anything changes `data` in the call to `super(f)`, that is overwritten by the `data = null;`.

As mentioned by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel), the way to avoid this is to not invoke overridable methods in constructors. This is covered in more detail in *Effective Java*, Item 19 (in the 3rd Ed - page 95 paragraph starting "Constructors must not invoke overridable methods").

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub(10);
        sub.init();
        sub.showData();
    }
}
```

not auto init